# InputNumberSpinner in popup doesn't fire set-method in JSF2/richfaces4

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, richfaces-modal

I'm trying to place a `rich:inputNumberSpinner` into a modal popup but the setter-Method of the value in the Bean doesn't react to any change on the spinner.

That's the Code of the xhtml:

```
<a4j:region>
      <rich:popupPanel id="attendance"
                       trimOverlayedElements="false"
                       modal="true" 
                       width="677"
                       height="460">
             <a4j:outputPanel id="panelAttendance">
                    <rich:inputNumberSpinner id="inputHoursMonday"
                                             disabled="#{Bean.inputHoursDisabled}"
                                             value="#{Bean.hoursMonday}"
                                             inputSize="1"
                                             step="0.25"
                                             immediate="true"
                                            validator="#{Validator.validateInputStep}">
                              <a4j:ajax event="change"  execute="@this"/>
                    </rich:inputNumberSpinner>
             </a4j:outputPanel>
    </rich:popupPanel>
</a4j:region>
```

When I use the spinner and try to change the value, the setter-Method in the Bean doesn't get called.
The same inputNumberSpinner works outside of the popup on the regular site.
So, anyone has a clue why the spinner doesn't work inside the popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PopupPanel is by default attached to body and thus outside of any form. Use `domElementAttachment="form"` (or "parent").